# Visual Studio - Web config transform remembers old attribute value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config

I'm posting this question because I've just spent 1 complete day searching for the answer that I didn't find anywhere.

The problem is that I have 3 environments for my application :

- Dev
- Qua
- Prod

So I have created a web config for each environment in order to change the database source. And I have also created a deploy profile for each environment in order to specify their respective server.

To test if my differents web config work as expected, I tried to swap every database source/server :
dev server with qua database, dev server with prod database and so on...

But, for each deploy, the server keep the related database source :

- Dev server => Dev Database
- Qua server => Qua Database
- Prod server => Prod Database

However, I followed every doc I found and tried a lot of alternatives from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN, using SetAttributes, Replace, Remove/Insert... but nothing resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't name your profiles like their web.config. Visual Studio seems to apply the web.config with the same name as the profile after the web.config you specified and overrides it.

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.